# How can I safely use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to avoid XSS?

Tags: security

I've seen a lot of warnings about using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because it can open things up to XSS, but I haven't been able to find anything confirming a safe way to use it. Some people have mentioned using `esc_url()`, but I wasn't able to find anything confirming how to safely use it. This is my best guess, would this safely prevent XSS attacks?

`echo esc_url(( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

If I want to use the URL internally rather than display it, it seems I have to use `esc_url_raw()`. Is this safe as well?

`$pageurl = esc_url_raw(( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: What are you using it for? Printing out in HTML or redirecting the user?

Comment: I'm using it to build another URL to share the current page on other sites such as twitter. So the final URL is being used in an href.

Comment: If you think things through, you should rarely even need to consider most `$_SERVER` values. If you can be more explicit about what you need to accomplish you will get more relevant answers.

Comment: @s_ha_dum That doesn't really help answer the question. I have thought things through, and in this case, I do need to access the $_SERVER variables. The question is how to do so safely.

Comment: `esc_attr` should be sufficient

Comment: No, it doesn't answer the question. That is why it is a comment. I am fishing for information.

Comment: Additionally, if this just about `$_SERVER` variable safety, it should be asked at [so].

Comment: @s_ha_dum The question is about esc_url() which is a WordPress specific function.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Can you explain a little bit more? Everything that I've read says that `esc_attr` is not for URLs.

Comment: @JosiahSprague `esc_attr` will ensure that malicious script/HTML cannot be injected from user input (i.e. `REQUEST_URI`), thus defeating a possible XSS attack.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Why use `esc_attr` over `esc_url`?

Comment: I may be wrong, but `esc_url` is more geared at escaping/sanitizing URL strings to conform to RFC standards. `esc_attr` is designed specifically to escape data for safe use in HTML attributes.

Comment: So in this case, why would you recommend `esc_attr` on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? @TheDeadMedic

Comment: Since you mentioned you'll be using it in an `href`, an HTML attribute, I opted for `esc_attr` (in actual fact you could use both, `esc_attr( esc_url( $url ) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are printing the URL out, say to the front end... that is, it is to be displayed as a normal URL to a visitor etc. then:

```
esc_url()
```

If you are going to use the URL in, say, a WordPress redirect (or anything else that sends http header 'location', then you will need:

```
esc_url_raw()
```

This is actually the basis and fix of this recent security vulnerability:
https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/security-advisory-xss-vulnerability-affecting-multiple-wordpress-plugins.html